# How can we create underline text which covers 50% height of text?

Tags: html, css

I got stuck on this issue. How can we create an underline text, which covers 50% height of text and also responsive on the small screen?
[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underline is actually a gradient background. It will be preserved after the line break:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, #7DE856 50%);
  padding: .1em .4em;
  
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<span>Sample Text</span>
<br>
<br>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Tempore necessitatibus obcaecati nisi quaerat! Provident eum ducimus impedit adipisci sequi.</span>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much. This is actually what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `::before` in `CSS`

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">text here</span>
<br>
<span class="text">sample text goes here</span>
<br>
<span class="text">text here</span>
```

Comment: How about multiple lines?

Comment: Edited my answer. use <br>